# Why doesn't "\n" work as a line break in HTML email?

Tags: android, newline, jakarta-mail, forward

My code sample is:

```
private String _body;
private String _forward;

// setup message body
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setContent(_body + "\n" + "--------------------------------" + "\n" + _forward , "text/html");
            _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

When I send this message to my email address it shows:

_body = "Yeni Yazi"
and _forward = "deneme mail 2"

[image]

Comment: your screenshot shows that the second "\n" worked correctly... did you try <br> instead of "\n" ?

Comment: Click on the down-arrow, and then on *Show original* to see what was actually sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're sending email as HTML text you should use `<br>` instead as that's the HTML line break.

Answer (score 2):

use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead, to make your code work on all operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `\r\n` instead of using `\n`. For **windows OS**, `\n` doesn't help. `\n` works perfectly in **Linux OS**